# Drag and drop sprite with Ext JS 7.0.0

Tags: extjs

I want to understand how to drag and drop a sprite with Ext JS 7. I know how to do it with version 4 but it doesn't work with version 7.

Do you have a link explaining how to do it?

Thank

Comment: Could you post a fiddle and add the information if this is ExtJS 7 classic or modern?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `spriteevents` plugin.

With the spriteevents plugin you have the options for `spritemousedown, -move and -up` events.

Here is a full example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3frt